# ¿Que es una API?

Tags: api

Estoy un poco confuso en el tema de una API y me gustaria saber, si el concepto es el que yo pienso.

Paso 1: Usuario utiliza la parte del cliente para la búsqueda

Paso 2: La información es recibida a una función que hace una petición al servidor.

Paso 3: El servidor le envía los datos encontrados.

Paso 4: La función devuelve al cliente lo que se ha podido encontrar con éxito o sin éxito.

Es decir, el paso 2 donde yo tengo las consultas SQL en este caso (es decir la comunicación con el servidor), seria una api?

Comment: Hola, Fernando. La pregunta es A) muy amplia, B) basada en opiniones. Es posible que termine cerrada por estas causas.

Comment: Si, el código corriendo en el servidor que te da respuestas y atiende lo que le pides es un tipo de API basada en la arquitectura cliente servidor. Igual también son API's las funciones o clases que ya vienen construidas en un lenguaje de programación listas para que las uses.

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/what-is-an-api-in-english-please-b880a3214a82/ este articulo lo encuentro bastante bueno para que te des una mejor idea

Comment: También encontré esta pregunta en el sitio en ingles con algunas respuestas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440379/what-exactly-is-the-meaning-of-an-api

Answer (score 6, accepted):

API: Application Programming Interface.

Usuario(Front End) <---------> API <---------> Server(Back End) <---> Base de datos

### Paso 1

Usuario realiza un pedido (http request) al API

### Paso 2

El API toma tu pedido y lo lleva a tu Server

### Paso 3

Tu server se comunica con tu Base de Datos encuentra el pedido lo prepara y le pasa de nuevo al API

### Paso 4

API lleva el pedido listo al Usuario.

---

Una forma que se utiliza para explicar es la del restaurante. Fijate en este [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s7wmiS2mSXY)

Cliente <---------> Mozo <---------> Cocina <---> Comidas

### Paso 1

Cliente mira el menu y realiza un pedido al Mozo

### Paso 2

El Mozo toma el pedido y lo lleva a la Cocina

### Paso 3

Cocina recibe el pedido prepara el plato y le da al mozo

### Paso 4

El mozo lleva el plato al cliente.

Answer (score 2):

Más que pasos, un api puede verse como una biblioteca o librería de métodos que usualmente se realizan para ser usados o invocados en distintos ámbitos, por ejemplo: Twitter tiene su propia api, entonces si tu deseas crear una aplicación que necesite realizar acciones relacionadas a Twitter, usarás su librería la cual ya trae todos los métodos necesarios para poder utilizar sus funcionalidades. La misma abstraccion se puede utilizar practicamente a todo, los lenguajes de programación se basan usualmente en librerías, en donde tienes una para cada cosa, por ejemplo siempre existirá una librería para SQL otra para tratamiento de fechas, otra para exponer servicios. Etc.